# LFSR in VHDL always generating zero

Tags: vhdl, modelsim

I have written a LFSR in VHDL. I have tested it in simulation and it works as expected (generates random integers between 1 and 512). However when I put it onto hardware it always generates "000000000"

The code is as follows:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;

entity LFSR is
    port(clk, reset : in bit;
         random     : out std_logic_vector (8 downto 0));
end entity LFSR;

architecture behaviour of LFSR is
    signal temp : std_logic_vector (8 downto 0) := (8 => '1', others => '0');
begin

    process(clk)
    begin
        if(clk'event and clk='1') then
            if(reset='0') then --reset on signal high, carry out normal function
                temp(0) <= temp(8);
                temp(1) <= temp(0);
                temp(2) <= temp(1) XOR temp(8);
                temp(3) <= temp(2) XOR temp(8);
                temp(4) <= temp(3) XOR temp(8);
                temp(8 downto 5) <= temp(7 downto 4);
            else
                --RESET
                temp <= "100000000";
            end if;
        end if;
        random <= temp;
    end process;

end architecture behaviour;
```

It was tested in Modelsim and compiled in Quartus II for a Cyclone III DE0 board.
Can anyone see why it is not working (in practice, the simulation is fine) and explain what I need to change to get it to work?

Comment: Move the `random <= temp;` statement inside the `end if;` or add `temp` to the sensitivity list and re-simulate, `random` was being updated on the falling edge of clock in simulation.   Your LFSR has a period of 186 clocks, generates 'some' pseudo random numbers between 1 and 511. Get any warnings during synthesis?  Have the pin out correct?

Comment: I have moved random <= temp; as suggested but the output is the same. 186 pseudo random numbers are sufficient for my purpose. No warnings relating to this component or signals. Pins are correct.

Comment: This doesn't look like a VHDL/simulation issue, rather a Quartus II synthesis/implementation issue.

Answer (score 0):

If `reset` is directly from a FPGA pin, then it is probably not synchronized
with `clk`, so proper synchronous reset operation is not ensured.

Add two flip-flops for synchronization of `reset` to `clk` before it is used in
the process.  This can be done with:

```
...
    signal reset_meta : bit;  -- Meta-stable flip-flop
    signal reset_sync : bit;  -- Synchronized reset

begin

    process(clk)
    begin
        if(clk'event and clk='1') then
            reset_meta <= reset;
            reset_sync <= reset_meta;
            if (reset_sync = '0') then  -- Normal operation
...
```

Altera have some comment about this in [External Reset Should be Correctly
Synchronized](http://quartushelp.altera.com/13.0/mergedProjects/verify/da/comp_file_rules_reset_external.htm).
The description covers flip-flops with asynchronous reset, but the use of two
flip-flops for synchronisation of external reset applies equally in your case.

Still remember to move the `random <= temp` inside the `if` as David pointed
out.

Comment: If QuartusII does default values for FFs it should run anyway even without reset.  The other one of course is the polarity of reset correct externally?  Is it running so fast you can't see anything?  These GPIO outputs?  How are you evaluating the output? The user manual shows 74HC245 'debounce' on Button 0-2) when  you should look at the [DE0 Debounce Project](https://www.terasic.com.tw/cgi-bin/page/archive_download.pl?Language=English&amp;No=364&amp;FID=9ff7cfce6a1d936ac012c5454546ee8d "DE0 Debounce Project").

Answer (score -1):

If you haven't any luck you might take a look at the synthesized schematic or perform post-synthesis simulation.  I occasionally swap RTL models out for post - synth models for verification if there's something that isn't obvious in behavioral simulation.
-Jerry